# Calculating the Lie Algebra of U(1) via the exponential map.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

We can define the Lie algebra of a matrix lie group $G$ via the following:
$$ Lie(G) = [ X \in M(n,\mathbb{C} \mid e^{t X} \in G \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}] $$
The group $U(1)$, complex numbers with modulus $1$, may be written as:
$$ [ e^{i \theta} \mid \theta \in \mathbb{R} ] $$

Then it seems to me that
$ Lie(U(1)) = [ r \in \mathbb{C} \mid e^{t r} = e^{i \theta} \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R} ] = i\mathbb{R} $.
Both online sources and textbooks state, however, that $Lie(U(1)) = \mathbb{R}$.
Is there an error in my calculation, or am I misunderstanding something more fundamental?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ and $i\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic by the Lie algebra isomorphism $x \to ix$.